# Node.JS Discord bot input

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm making a discord bot and need to capture text from a users command such as !add var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 with vars being information that needs to be placed into mysql. the code functions well as is but I'm new to node.js and discord and can't find anything on google on how to capture command input to use as database values.

```
const prefix = "!";
client.on("message", message => {
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "kos")) {
    connection.query("SELECT kos_id, kos_name, kos_coords,kos_seenby FROM rogue_kos ORDER BY 
kos_name", function(err, rows, fields) {
    rows.forEach(function(row) {
    console.log(row.kos_id, row.kos_name, row.kos_coords, row.kos_seenby, row.kos_date);
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle('Records Management')
        .setColor(3447003)
        .setDescription('Please select an option.')
        .setTimestamp()
        .addField('1. View KoS List', 'Respond with "1" to SEARCH records')
        .addField('2. Add to KoS List', 'Respond with "2" to ADD a record - Currently 
Unavailable.');
        message.channel.send({embed})


        message.channel.awaitMessages(response => (response.content === '1' || response.content === 
"2"), {
            max: 1,
            time: 100000,
            errors: ['time']
        }).then(mg => {
            if (mg.first().content === "1"){ //Have to use .first() because mg is a Collection
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle('Search Results')
        .setColor(3447003)
        .setDescription('ID | NAME | COORDS | ADDED BY | DATE ADDED\n\n' + row.kos_id + ' | ' + 
row.kos_name + ' | ' + row.kos_coords + ' | ' + row.kos_seenby + ' | ' + row.kos_date)
        .setTimestamp()
        message.channel.send({embed})
            }else if (mg.first().content === "2"){
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle('Add Record')
        .setColor(3447003)
        .setDescription('Currently Unavailable')
        .setTimestamp()
        message.channel.send({embed})
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            message.channel.send("Ran out of time!");
        })
    })
})
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the syntax is the same, but with an sqlite3 database you would use a query like this

```
const arg = commandArgs;
const user = message.author;
const query = `UPDATE yourTableNameHere SET yourColumn=? WHERE user_id= ?`
  db.run(query, [arg, user],(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err.message);
    }
***your if/else statements here***    
});
```

Of course this isn't exact, but it may give you an idea of how to do it. Also, you would want to add restrictions and checks to make sure the command argument is what you're expecting.

Comment: Ok I'll try this and see how it goes and let you know thanks.

Comment: Actually, now that I've slept on it, I would recommend making that a callback function and using it that way. It's how I've written all my update code and it works nicely, although you don't have to.

Also, is the information you're updating also a part of a discord collection? If it is you need to add something else to update both.

Comment: the collection portion can be ignored, problem i'm having since i'm new to this type of coding is seperating each value from command input and using them in the insert statement instead of having multiple command values going into one column. so each value after whitespace needs its own var or something to that effect if that makes sense
so as an idea how would i go about this:

    `!add name level coords self   is the input
    some code here to translate or split those 4 values

    connection.query("INSERT INTO $name, $level, $coords, $self FROM`

Comment: That's where a call back statement comes in handy, you use an check like

```
if(arg.length > 1) {
 var argsSplit = JSCodeToSplitArgs;
callback1.argsSplit[0];
callback2.argsSplit[1]; //ext...
```